# Titanium content assistant not working

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, content-assist

The content assistant is not working.

I'm working on OSX, Titanium Studio, iOS & Android mobile app and have tried the following:

1. Installing the following SDKs: 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0.
2. Tried reverting between those versions.
3. Checked the Project Natures (mobile - primary, mobile module, are checked).
4. Tried every option on the Project Build Path.
5. Of course tried to build the project again and again.
6. Check the content assistant preference both in the main preference and in the project properties.

Are the any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the 3.2.0GA SDK (3.2.1 and 3.3.0 are not official releases yet). As far as I have heard it is known and should be fixed in the next SDK update. Only question is when this update will be out.

You can get content assist back by reverting to 3.1.3GA, but that doesn't help you much if you need features from 3.2.0GA.

**EDIT:**
The issue is described in [this JIRA-ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-5989) and as it mentions should be resolved in the upcoming 3.2.1 release.